# Quantile Regression Detrending

Tags: regression, trend, quantile-regression

Assume I have a time series, as the black one below. As shown, the quantile regression for 5%, 25%, 50%, 75%, and 95% quantiles show different slopes (in red). Even if not quite visible, the ratio between upper and lower trends is approximatively 2, which makes a critical difference.

[image]

I would like to fit an ARMA model. This requires to make the series stationary, i.e. to remove the trend and the seasonality. I will not deal with seasonality here, but only with trend. The use of a classical linear regression for the trend would require to estimate that trend, and simply deduct it from the original time series.

- However, for the quantile regression, I have multiple trend lines. How can I properly remove each of them to my original dataset ? The idea here is to make sure that the upper quantiles are "more detrended" than the lower quantiles.
- Now, assuming that I've successfully detrended (and deseasoned) my series, and that I'm able to fit and simulate an ARMA process, my simulations will be stationary. How can I re-trend them, taking into account each single trend, to properly simulate something that looks like the black curve ?

For the sake of the example, I've just used a `data.frame` named `myts` with a `Date` and a `Temperature` column :

```
library(quantreg)

plot(myts$Date, myts$Temperature, type = "l", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Temperature")
abline(rq(Temperature ~ Date, tau = 0.5, data = myts), col="red", lwd = 2)
abline(rq(Temperature ~ Date, tau = 0.25, data = myts), col="red", lwd = 2)
abline(rq(Temperature ~ Date, tau = 0.75, data = myts), col="red", lwd = 2)
abline(rq(Temperature ~ Date, tau = 0.05, data = myts), col="red", lwd = 2)
abline(rq(Temperature ~ Date, tau = 0.95, data = myts), col="red", lwd = 2)
```

Comment: This depends entirely on how you detrend your time series. If you were to detrend it by using a time slope, then you can retrend it by simply extrapolating the line.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I actually detrend the series first ? While for linear regression you just need to do your actual series minus the trend, this doesn't seem obvious for quantile regression, because you have as much trend lines as you want.

Comment: If you model this using ARMA, then you are not doing quantile regression. (I don't really know how useful a quantile regression on a linear trend of time is, which does not account for the rather obvious seasonality in your series.) If you suspect changing variance, you could model residuals from your ARIMA using GARCH. (But the differences in slope are minor, and especially with my misgivings about the quantile regression in the first place, I find it a bit doubtful that GARCH will do much more than model "noise in noise".) Anyway, what is your goal? Forecasting? Something else?

Comment: Thanks @StephanKolassa. An ARMA model requires to work on a de-trended and de-seasoned series first. Seasonality will be estimated using a sum of cos and sin. But for the trend, I want to switch from one single trend (may it be linear, or kernel, or whatever), to multiple ones coming from quantile regression : my assumption is that, in this case, trend is lower for low quantiles compared to high quantiles (the ratio is approximatively 2 in my dataset). My goal is indeed to forecast, by making sure that low quantiles will stay "low" and high quantiles will still increase

Comment: *"How can I properly remove the different trends to the whole dataset ?"* By including it properly into the model. Adding the seasonality should ideally be part of this as well. In addition, it is not clear how you fit ARMA as a quantile regression. Those are three issues, which makes it unclear what your question is really about.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, It seems like my question was not appropriately formulated from the above comments. I've edited my question, hoping this will make more sense.

Comment: @Vincent it seems like the median/mean as well as the interquartile range / variance are not stable. De-trending deals with the median, but not with the interquartile range. It is difficult to say how to undo that part without taking seasonality into account (the increase can be due to the amplitude of the seasonality, instead of the noise of an ARMA model). Also, these trends are very weak and it seems difficult to say what we are looking at without domain knowledge. You can fit this in all sorts of ways and it is unclear what you want precisely.

Comment: Put it this way : forget about the ARMA and everything. Just assume a standard y = f(x) relationship. If the relationship is linear then I can write y = a*x + b + e. Let's denote y - (a*x + b) the detrended values.
In my case, I have, say, 5 different trends a_n*x + b_n, 1 <= n <= 5, corresponding to 5 quantiles thresholds of y.
How can I detrended y using those 5 trends, i.e. y - g(a_n, b_n, x), where g is what I'm trying to determine ?

Comment: @Vincent you can determine the trend by fitting it to your data. There is no possibility of multiple trends unless you use multiple definitions for 'trend', but you can only 'detrend' one of them. If ax+b is your trend then use that in your model. Possibly you want to subtract a trend and *also* perform a scaling to make the variance constant?